# What happens to classes removed from collections and arrays

Tags: vba, excel, class, collections

I have created multiple instances of a class `myClass`, and have stored them in a collection. I would like to know what happens to the object in memory when it is removed from the collection. i.e.

```
Sub createCollection()
Dim c As New Collection
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 5
    c.Add New myClass
Next i
c.Remove(5) 'remove last item
End Sub
```

Is the class still there in memory, does removing it from the collection remove it entirely, as it is not referenced anywhere else? What is the effect (if any) of using a collection declared publically instead, or removing the item with a different Sub, say a button press?

What about for an Array:

```
Sub createCollection()
Dim a() As myClass
Redim a(1 To 5)
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 5
    Set a(i) = New myClass
Next i
Redim Preserve a(1 To 4) 'remove last item
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects lives as long as somewhere a reference exists to it. When no reference exists the object is released from memory.

```
Dim a As myClass
Set a = New myClass
```

Here `a` holds reference to a place in memory where the object of type `myClass` resides. As long as this reference exists the object will be in the memory.

```
  Set a = Nothing
```

Now the `a` doesn't reference the location of memory where the object resides. When this was the last reference then this object will be released.

```
Dim a As myClass
Dim b As myClass
Set a = New myClass
Set b = a

Set a = Nothing
```

Now the object still continues to live because there is reference to it held in variable `b`. You can still say e.g. `b.Something = 1000`.

```
Set b = Nothing
```

Now the object can be removed from memory if the reference held in `b` was the last one.

> I would like to know what happens to the object in memory when it is removed from the collection

In this case you can watch it by yourself when slightly modifying the code.

```
Sub createCollection()
    Dim c As New Collection
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 5
        c.Add New myClass
        c(i).Id = i
    Next i
    c.Remove (5) 'remove last item
End Sub
```

> myClass Class

```
Private m_id As String

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    MsgBox "Object termination: " & m_id
End Sub

Public Property Let Id(ByVal vNewValue As Variant)
    m_id = vNewValue
End Property
```

The references to those five objects are held in the collection. So when object is created the `New` operator returns the reference to memory and this reference is stored in the `VBA.Collection`. When you remove the object from the collection then the object will be released from memory and the message box from `Class_Terminate` will confirm that. After the method `createCollection` finishes then the variable `c` which is holding the reference to the collection goes out of scope and then the collection can be released because no other reference exists to it. Then the four remaining objects will be released as well which will be confirmed with the message from `Class_Terminate`. HTH

Answer (score 2):

In OOP object is removed from memory when last reference to it is removed. So, when there's no reference to ceratin object it will be removed on next garbage collection. In your case, your array is an array of references and the way you create this, they are the only references. So if you remove last item, you also remove last reference to this object. So in next garbage collection, the object will be removed from memory.